# Как обрезать текст до последнего пробела?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как модифицировать код, чтобы обрезать текст на 180 символов до последнего пробела

```
<?php  echo mb_substr($item->introtext, 0, 180).'...'; ?>
```

Comment: Если в тексте точно не встретится символ новой строки, можно так: `substr($string, 0, strpos(wordwrap($string, 180), "\n"));`  ([отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79986/556876)). Замените `substr()` на `mb_substr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте моё решение:

```
<?php
$text = "lorem ipsum set";
$max_lengh = 20;

if(mb_strlen($text, "UTF-8") > $max_lengh) {
    $text_cut = mb_substr($text, 0, $max_lengh, "UTF-8");
    $text_explode = explode(" ", $text_cut);

    unset($text_explode[count($text_explode) - 1]);

    $text_implode = implode(" ", $text_explode);

    echo $text_implode."...";
} else {
    echo $text;
}
?>
```

Comment: "lorem ipsum" лишится ipsum'а, жаль его. А ведь короче 20.

Comment: Ваш метод сработал! Спасибо! Но единственное "Но"! если у меня текст меньше 180 символов, то по-любому режет до последнего слова. Можно сделать, чтобы в случае когда текст не превышен на 180 символов его не резало?

Comment: обновил код, если он Вам помог, выберите правильный ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос

Comment: Обновленный код замечательно работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Щас заминусуют но можно и так

```
<?php
    $text = explode(' ',$text);
    $text = $text[count($text)-1];
    echo $text;
?>
```

или если нужна часть 180 символов до первого пробела после

```
<?php 
  $pos = mb_strpos($item->introtext, ' ', 180);
  if(!$pos) {
    $pos = 180;
  }
  echo mb_substr($item->introtext, 0, $pos).'...'; 
?>
```

И ищё один извращённый способ

```
  <?php
        if(strlen($text) > 180) {
          $textArray = explode(' ',$text);
          $textForReplace = $textArray[count($textArray)-1];
          echo str_replace($textForReplace,'',$text); 
        } else {
          echo $text;
        }
    ?>
```

за который не грех и downvote схватить.
с пробелом в лево можно и так

```
<?php 
$textOrig = mb_substr($textOrig, 0, 70);
$text = explode(' ',$textOrig);
$text = $text[count($text)-1];

echo str_replace($text,'',$textOrig).'...';
?>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a65f12c4d80bd6aae93dd6252c26a6272c9f104 посмотреть сдесь

Comment: ТС хотел, мне кажется, сокращать длинный текст так, чтобы разрез проходил по пробелу. Т.е. остаться должна левая часть строки, не длиннее 180 символов. А уйти – некий (не обязательно последний) пробел и всё, что за ним.

Comment: @Sergiks да вы правы сейчас что нибудь придумаем

Comment: По-моему, всё же, до первого пробела **до**. И только, если строка длиннее 180.

Comment: @Sergiks отредактировал с использованием offset и strpos

Comment: лучше `mb_strpos()`, наверное. Многоточие приделывать только если исходный текст сократили. Искать нужно пробел *влево* от 180-й позиции.

Comment: не поленитесь протестировать ваш код ; )

Comment: @Sergiks да вы правы протестил и ошибка закралась

Comment: @Sergiks да вообще не понятно, что ТС хочет, показ бы пример, как есть и как нужно

Comment: Проверьте ваш код на длине 70 и строке `проверка связи на кириллице и latinitse и ещё всяких венгерских á и прочих странных символах, много длиннее 70`

Comment: @Sergiks да есть баг со `string_replace` он получил `про` и заменил все вхождения `про`

Comment: Ребята, спасибо за помощь. Но не сработал ни один из методов - просто не отображается вводный текст. у меня joomla  и на  метод с mb_strpos   она ругается Warning: mb_strpos(): Offset not contained in string in . Соответственно отображается все некорректно.

Comment: @Ivan добавь условие если больше 180 то обрезать иначе не получиться и смотри ответ нижениже марселя ардуанова.

Answer (score 3):

Обрезаем, находим последний пробел и обрезаем по нему

```
$text = mb_substr($text, 0, 180);
$text = mb_substr($text, 0, mb_strrpos($text,' '));
```

Comment: опечатка у вас в `mb_strrpos`

Comment: @Naumov [`mb_strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strrpos.php) – век живи, век учись )

Comment: @Sergiks эх и в правду есть такая ) но с одним символом я думаю позиция вхождения будет равна

Comment: попробовал ваш метод, не отображается вовсе ничего. возмонжо я неправильно применил код, так как в этом деле полный нуб. но я думаю mb_strpos не обрабатывает моя cms

Comment: @Ivan, вероятно вам нужно указать кодировку 'UTF-8' в mb_ функциях дополнительным параметром , либо поставить mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');